# how to retain kword entred for searching in search dialog of android throughout application?

Tags: android

i have an application that provide search option on each activity , i want search box to display last word search.How to retain last word searched?

Comment: You can accept answers to your question by clicking on a check icon near the answer. You should accept answers if you've found them useful.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

1 - shared preference

or

2 - Keep a Variable in Application file  which is accessible from through any activity

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) post describing ways to store data in Android. You should decide what's the best solution for your application. Hope this helps.

Comment: i only need to retain last searched keyword & display in search dialog until new word is searched  , not the list of keywords that were searched .I can store last keyword searched in a variable but problem is how to show it in search dialog

Comment: @napster, You should provide you application's code to make it easier to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, just consider using a SharedPreference.
Then each time a user search for something, save it in your SharedPreferenes as a String, and then in each search field you read that that String and put it there as default, if this is the first time searching it will return null or "". That's a behavior when reading values from SharedPreferenes that you have to specify a default value.

Comment: can you please write code of accomplishing the task am new to android